# mortality problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The mortality problem is the question if some product of a given set of matrices
 yields the 0-matrix. In general, the mortality problem is undecidable. To have a
 feeling for the difficulty of the problem, I only considered two 3x3-matrices with
 entries -1..1. The hardest problem I found so far is

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ B = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1\\ -1 & -1 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Solution : [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

0 stands for A, 1 for B, so $AB^2A^3B^4A^2BAB^2A=0$. There is no shorter
 product, the optimal length is 17.

An obvious condition for the matrices A and B is $\det(A)\det(B)=0$

Now my questions

- Is the mortality problem decidable for two 3x3-matrices ?
- What is the maximal possible length of an optimal solution depending
  on the size of the entries ?
- How can it be proven that the general mortality problem is undecidacle,
  and where are the limits for decidability ?

  My new record is :

18
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

a

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

b

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: There are only finitely many three-by-three matrices with entries -1, 0, 1, so if every pair is mortal, then it is decidable that every pair is mortal. So if the problem is undecidable, then there exists an immortal pair. Have you tried posting this to MathOverflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is undecidable for 3x3 matrices with integer entries:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems#Problems_about_matrices

Therefore, there is no (computable) bound on the size of the optimal solution.
(otherwise one could decide the problem by first computing the bound, then testing all possible answers of this size)

More details and I guess an answer to your third point here:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0644

Comment: According to the paper M(2,3x3) has not been shown to be undecidable. So this question  is still open in the case (?)